# Convergence of sequence $0.333...$ to $\frac13$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to prove the Convergence of sequence $0.333...$ to $\frac13$ using the epsilon definition of sequence convergence.

My attempt:
I assume the limit is $\frac13$. So by the definition,
$$|\frac3{10^n}-\frac13|<\epsilon$$ $\forall n\ge\kappa(\epsilon)$

Now, I am unable to continue. I am not sure how to remove the $|\cdot|$ sign from the inequality.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{3}{10^i}}$?

Comment: @BernardPan Yes. But I have not been taught series yet. Only notions of sequences allowed :-)

Comment: Then your sequence should be $a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n 3/10^i$ and you should consider $|a_n - 1/3|$, or I would rather consider $|3a_n - 1|$.

Comment: Another way to say it is $-\epsilon<\frac3{10^n}-\frac13<\epsilon$

Comment: @CyclotomicField Then? I need to find an inequality of n to substitute that for k. isn't it? How will I do it here?

Comment: You can get properly sized vertical bars (and other paired delimiters that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot do series, then the best way is to express the $n$th term in terms of $n$ only, without requiring a sum. This can be done easily.

For example, note that $0.\underbrace{333\ldots 333}_{n \text{ times}} = \frac{10^{n} - 1}{3 \times 10^n}$, verified by direct multiplication.

Therefore, the quantity whose limit is required is $\frac{10^n - 1}{3 \times 10^n}$ Rewrite :
$$
\frac{10^n-1}{3 \times 10^n} = \frac 13 - \frac 1{3 \times 10^n} \implies \left|\frac{10^n - 1}{3 \times 10^n} - \frac 13\right| = \frac{1}{3 \times 10^n} 
$$

Now, given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ large enough so that $10^N > \frac{1}{3\epsilon}$. This is seen to satisfy the definition of the limit, and easily enough the limit must be $\frac 13$.

Answer (score 3):

As we can see,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{3}{10^i}}=0.\underbrace{333\ldots 3}_{n\ 3's}<\frac{1}{3}.$$

Thus,

$$\frac{1}{3}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{3}{10^i}}=0.\underbrace{000\ldots 0}_{n\ 0's}333\ldots<\frac{4}{10^{n+1}}.$$

Then we can simply let

$$\frac{4}{10^{n+1}}<\varepsilon\implies n\geq\left\lceil\lg\frac{4}{\varepsilon}-1\right\rceil.$$